# avoid greylisting with postfix

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, greylisting

I have an email marketing app, so we have a great volume of mails to send and sometimes a great volume to the same MX. Depending the MX configuration we enter in a greylist and the server told us (in the log) to wait some minutes or second to continue sending messages to him. But postfix isn't smart enough to hold the messages to that domain that are in the queue.

So I wrote a log parser that gets the mail.log and in case it find any greylist warning it hold the messages to that domain. But I am not sure if this is the best/the right way to do it.

Do you have any other suggestions?

Yeah, I think I was not much clear in what I said. My postfix is with default configurations. What I have said is that when my server send a great volume to one MX this MX stop accepting my messages and tell my server that it is being greylisted and I should wait some minutes to continue sending messages to that MX.

I know that my server will try to send those messages again, but if ignore those graylist warnings and keep sending to that MX I got a bad deliverability.

Comment: Postfix, by default, doesn't exhibit this behavior.  You've thus configured it strangely.  If you post the output of `postconf -n` and some log messages showing it doing this, we may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

you have a very strange postfix... i'm using almost default configuration of postfix under debian and it handles temporary bounces caused by greylisting without any problems.

whole idea of greylisting is based on the assumption that client implements smtp protocol correctly and when faced with temporary rejection / 4xx will re-try delivering message later.

Comment: There's a possibility that the OP...not posting enough details...is sending so much mail that the resulting mail queue is causing quite a backload on the server. Or he's trying to get out the emails in a timely manner. Usually questions like this make my common sense tingle...hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the domain and your relationship with them, you might work with them to have the restrictions lifted on your domain.

Otherwise, I don't know if there is a simple way around it other than throttling back your rate of sending. It's not that it wasn't smart enough to throttle back, it's that Postfix wasn't really meant for marketing mails so you may need to look at a proprietary solution to do it.

If you're really not a spammer and these emails are being requested by your customers you shouldn't have anything to lose in emailing the other site's admin to work with them on finding a solution.